# Linking Two Models Together in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been stuck on this all day.  I have a setup like the one below.  I'm trying to define friends using the group_memberships association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships
  has_many :friends # what goes here? <<
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :group
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, :through > :group_memberships
end
```

I'd like to do this without creating a join table for friends, unless it's completely crazy to do it without.

The group_membership table contains user_id and group_id linking one user to one group.

I'd trying to get

```
@user.friends
```

to return users with common group_memberships using the group_id.

```
has_many :friends, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :group
```

Nothing I've tried works, but I'll chalk that up to my complete misunderstanding of the above code.

Comment: Do you want other users that share all the same groups as @user, or share any group with @user.  For example.  @user is a member of groups 1 and 2.  Sally is a member of group 1 and 2 and Bob is only a member of group 1.  Is @user.friends Sally or Sally and Bob?

Comment: @user.friends would be Sally and Bob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Rails doesn't let you nest has_many's more than 2 deep..  Forgetting about naming it `friends` for a moment (let's call it `users` instead), this would theoretically be what you'd want:

```
has_many :group_memberships
has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships
has_many :users, :through => groups
```

Except that this doesn't work.  If you try it you'll see [this](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L33) not-so-helpful error message which comes from [this](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L300-302) bit of code, specifically `source_reflection.options[:through].nil?`.  That is, the `through` isn't allowed to have a `through` itself.

Instead, you may want to do something like this:

### Solution 1

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships

  def friends
    groups.with_users.map(&:users).flatten.uniq.reject{|u| u == self}
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :group_memberships

  named_scope :with_users, :include => :users
end
```

### Solution 2

Use the [`nested_has_many_through`](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through/tree/master) plugin that Radar mentioned.  It looks like at least [one fork](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through/network) of it on github has been updated to work on the latest Rails.

### Solution 3 (just for kicks)

or, just for kicks, you could do it with one big SQL query:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships

  def friends
    sql = <<-SQL
      SELECT users.* FROM users, (
        SELECT DISTINCT gm2.user_id AS user_id
        FROM group_memberships gm, groups g, group_memberships gm2
        WHERE gm.user_id = ? AND g.id = gm.group_id AND gm2.group_id = g.id AND gm2.user_id != ?
      ) AS user_ids
      WHERE users.id = user_ids.user_id
    SQL
    User.find_by_sql([sql, id, id])
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't have to do ugly sql. Check out my answer.

Comment: The solution w/ ugly SQL was just for fun. The first solution just has a named scope and some filtering, no SQL at all. The plugin you mentioned does look cool though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [nested_has_many_through](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through/tree/master) plugin.

Comment: Link broken, try this: http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

delegate :users, :to => 'group'

Comment: Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: `delegate` would only work if it were `group`, not `groups`.  Since `user.groups.users` doesn't work, `delegate :users, :to => 'groups'` wouldn't work either.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#M000102